# Turn off perl-debug-m ansi escape sequences on Windows 7

Tags: windows, debugging, raku, ansi-escape

On Windows 7 cmd.exe, the perl6-debug-m script outputs ansi escape sequences to set the colors, I suppose.  How do I suppress these codes or at least make them functional?  I'm just getting started with Perl 6 after working with Perl 4 and Perl 5 for over 20 years.  I need this to work on Windows because of a program I'm trying to port from Perl 5.

```
C:\rakudo\bin\lib>perl6 -v
This is Rakudo Star version 2018.04.1 built on MoarVM version 2018.04.1
implementing Perl 6.c.

C:\rakudo\bin\lib>perl6-debug-m
←[35m>>> LOADING ←[0m<REPL 1>
←[34m+ <REPL 1> (1 - 1)←[0m
←[34m| ←[0m←[1;33mREPL←[0m
←[34m> ←[0mquit
←[34m- ←[0mRun END blocks (y/N)?

C:\rakudo\bin\lib>perl6 -V |grep -v "moar:"
distro::auth=unknown
distro::desc=2018-05-20T09:17:12.587605-04:00
distro::is-win=True
distro::name=mswin32
distro::path-sep=;
distro::release=unknown
distro::signature=
distro::version=6.3
kernel::arch=unknown
kernel::archname=unknown-win32
kernel::auth=unknown
kernel::bits=64
kernel::desc=
kernel::hardware=unknown
kernel::name=win32
kernel::release=unknown
kernel::signature=
kernel::version=unknown
perl6::build-date=2018-05-07T10:08:20Z
perl6::codename=
perl6::implementation=Rakudo Star
perl6::language_version=6.c
perl6::libdir=C:\rakudo\share
perl6::prefix=C:\rakudo
perl6::release-number=
perl6::source-digest=688d0872d150048d083b7a499e9fc7a9e8b6ab5b
perl6::version=2018.04.1
repo::chain=inst#C:\Users\danhale\.perl6 inst#C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site inst#C:\rakudo\share\perl6\vendor inst#C:\rakudo\share\perl6 ap# nqp# perl5#
```

Comment: Can you use [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6#finding-powershell-in-windows-10-81-80-and-7)? It seems to work well with ANSI, and [allow some configuration options](https://superuser.com/questions/1264444/using-ansi-escape-codes-in-powershell-prompt-to-add-color-looses-meaning-after)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work for me.  Under powershell the perl6-debug-m.bat script still outputs the escape sequences, not color changes.

`C:\Users\danhale>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\danhale> perl6-debug-m
←[35m>>> LOADING ←[0m<REPL 1>
←[34m+ <REPL 1> (1 - 1)←[0m
←[34m| ←[0m←[1;33mREPL←[0m
←[34m> ←[0m'

Comment: you might need to install a program such as this one... https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/

Answer (score 5):

There's currently no way to disable them (I just checked the debugger interface's source to verify that). I've previously used [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) on Windows in order to work with applications that produce ANSI color codes, including the Perl 6 debugger, and recall that it rendered them fine.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  I found I needed to run ansicon whenever a new command window is opened.  I wrote a wrapper script p6db.cmd to do this every time, just in case.

@ ANSICON.EXE c:\rakudo\bin\perl6-debug-m.bat "%*"

Comment: Now that I've RTFM for ansicon :), I realize I can make it permanently apply to current and future invocations of cmd.exe by invoking it once with the -i flag.  So there's no need for my p6db wrapper script.